# Mock network requests in Cypress

Tags: node.js, request, cypress

I've been tearing my hair out over this for ages now - and I hope someone can help me :)

I've been trying to stub a network request in Cypress for ages now.

**commands.js**

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (
    email = 'email',
    password = 'pass'
) => {
    cy.server();
    cy.visit('url');
    cy.get('input[name="username"').type(email);
    cy.get('form').submit();
    cy.get('input[name="password"').type(password);
    cy.get('form').submit();
});
```

**mock.js**

```
describe('mock', function() {
    it('user can login', function() {
        cy.login();
        cy.get('main[role="main"]');

        cy.route('GET',
            '**/getIncentives*',
            {info: {}, results: {}}
        ).as('oppty');

        cy.wait('@oppty');
    });
});
```

**Chrome dev tools request**
[image]

**Cypress request failed**
[image]

Any help here would be really appreciated - I've been going crazy!

Thanks so much,
Ollie

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cypress will only find the network request *after* it's been aliased. The code in your question indicated you're not doing an action that would cause a network request:

```js
        cy.route('GET',
            '**/getIncentives*',
            {info: {}, results: {}}
        ).as('oppty');

       // cypress expected something to cause a network request here

        cy.wait('@oppty');
```

You should either move the call to `route` earlier in the test, or move the code that causes the request after the call to `route`.

Answer (score 6):

[Currently, Cypress `cy.route` can only stub network requests that use `XHRs`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Syntax)

Native HTML form elements don't use [XMLHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), hence you cannot use `cy.route` to stub it.

Most people don't run into this issue because using native HTML forms is [not as common nowadays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42304950/html-form-versus-xmlhttprequest)

#### Edit:

You are also `waiting` on the route, but haven't actually done anything in your test. Your test should look something like this:

```js
  cy.route('GET',
      '**/getIncentives*',
      {info: {}, results: {}}
  ).as('oppty');

  // cypress code that would cause a network request.

  cy.wait('@oppty');
```

Also, make sure the request is of type:`XHR`:
[image]

Comment: Hi Bkucera - the request that's actually failing is the `@oppty` request - not the form. I should have made that way clearer.

Will edit when I get home - thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Also note that cy.route() may not work with **server side rendering** (apparently).
I've had this problem when using NextJs, and solved it by first calling some other page, then **navigate on the client** to the page I actually want to test.

Like so:

```
describe('test cy.route', function() {
  it( 'test 1', () => {

    cy.server();
    cy.route({
        method: 'GET',
        url: /.*\/api\/someApiCall/,
        response: { 'someApiResponse': 'ok' },
        status: 200
    } ).as('myRouteAlias');

    // go to start page: first page is server side rendered. cy.route doesn't work.
    cy.visit('/');

    // go to page to be tested: client side, cy.route works then.
    cy.get( `a[href="/pageToBeTested"` ).should('exist').click();

    // wait for page loaded
    cy.url().should('include', 'pageToBeTested' );  

    // do something that requests '/api/someApiCall'.
    invokeFunctionThatDoesTheRequest();

    // wait for the request
    cy.wait('@myRouteAlias');

  });
});
```